# Google Sheets Formula Help needed - Vlookup/Index/Match

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, vlookup

this is my first time on here, I'm hoping someone can help me :)

I have a formula that finds the final occurrence of a value in a range and gives me the date for that occurrence

=ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(2,1/('Active Inventory'!$F$2:$F$400=$G3),'Active Inventory'!$A$2:$A$400))

It works great, the problem is I need to return the next date in the cells below the given one. here is a formula that gives me the next cell (date) after of the **first** occurrence of my value

=INDEX('Active Inventory'!$A$2:$A$400,MATCH($G8,'Active Inventory'!$F$2:$F$400,0)+1,)

but how do I get the next Date down (even when there are some cells below with the same date) after the **last** occurrence of my value?

Link to Sample document
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yDc1fXIH_S6WxsqFGHi9VUW_d4V5aTeaT7fv5c_xR1c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/169354/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: Please add your _manually entered_ desired results in the sample spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter()` to get the shift of the last occurrence of a container name, then another `filter()` to get shifts that come after that shift, and finally `single()` to get the first one, like this:

```
=iferror( 
  single( 
    filter( 
      'Active Inventory'!A$2:A, 
      'Active Inventory'!A$2:A 
      > 
      filter(
        'Active Inventory'!A$2:A, 
        row('Active Inventory'!A$2:A) 
        = 
        xmatch(B2, 'Active Inventory'!D$1:D, 0, -1) 
      ) 
    ) 
  ), 
  "no next shift" 
)
```

Format the results the same way you format shifts.

Comment: Wow, thank you, That worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

You may try with XMATCH from bottom to top search:

```
=INDEX('Active Inventory'!$A$2:$A$400,XMATCH($G8,'Active Inventory'!$F$2:$F$400,0,-1)+1,)
```

Comment: That worked exactly as it should Thank You! - but i just realized I need the next date down even though there are more rows below that have the same date.

Comment: Could you please add some details about it in the question? Add some table and sample desired output in the original question

Comment: I have added a sample document. I cannot give access to the original because it is company property.

Comment: I need to return the next Date and shift AM/PM after the date and shift when a chemical container stopped showing up in column "D" Active Inventory Tab

Comment: Even when that next shift may be many rows down